# How to speed up numpy array boolean masking in python?

Tags: python

I need to speed up the following boolean masking in python:

```
import numpy as np

# test dataset
n=1000000
mask = np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=(n,), p=[0.8, 0.2])
arr = np.random.rand(n)

# the code I need to speed up:
res = arr[mask]
```

Any ideas to make it faster in python?

Comment: no, that is probably the fastest it will be. Write a C-extension? Even then, I doubt it would be significantly faster.

Comment: You could try Numba: https://numba.pydata.org/

Comment: ＠juanpa.arrivillaga I don't think so. There might be a way to speed it up. We never know.

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann Do you want to give it a try?

Comment: @f. c. No, to be quite frankly

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann Do you think using GPU could help speedup dramatically?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a numba implementation, which has almost the same performance as the numpy one.

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit(parallel=False, fastmath=True)
def array_masking_float(arr, mask, res):
    j=0
    for i in nb.prange(mask.shape[0]):
        if mask[i] == True:
            res[j] = arr[i]
            j += 1
```

Can anyone come up with a better solution?